# How do I determine the efficiency of mouse movement from Point A to Point B in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to create an analytical program which keeps track of user mouse movement on a website and stores the data in a DB. Here is where I am stuck:

Assuming the mouse is always starting at the middle of the screen, and the user is instructed to move it to a particular element, how do I determine the efficiency and accuracy of that movement. I need to keep in mind the duration from start of hovering till the click, but I want to also include the hovering path of the mouse.

A perfect score would be a perfect line from Point A to Point B in x seconds, how do I determine the score of a curved path in 2x seconds, or an instance where the path goes in the wrong direction before proceeding to Point B? Are there any algorithms in existence?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you are asking us to design an algorithm that is not yet clear in your mind. This site is for when you have an algorithm, you tried to implement it, and you are facing a technical problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft8yLuqy/) that I created. Click on the START box and then click on the FINISH box. Hopefully this will help you get started.

```
var start = false;
var start_time,end_time;
var points = [];

$("#start").click(function() {
    start = true;
    points = [];
    start_time = Date.now();
});

$("#finish").click(function() {
    start = false;
    distance = travelledDistance();
    time = (Date.now() - start_time)/1000;

    var center_x_start = $("#start").offset().left + $("#start").width() / 2;
    var center_y_start = $("#start").offset().top + $("#start").height() / 2;
    var center_x_finish = $("#finish").offset().left + $("#finish").width() / 2;
    var center_y_finish = $("#finish").offset().top + $("#finish").height() / 2;

    var straight_distance = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(center_x_finish - center_x_start, 2) + Math.pow(center_y_finish - center_y_start, 2)));

    $("#time").text(+time+"s");
    $("#distance").text(distance+"px");
    $("#straight_distance").text(straight_distance+"px");

});

$(document).mousemove(function( event ) {
    if(!start)
        return;
    points.push(event.pageX + "," + event.pageY);
});

function travelledDistance(){
    var distance = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) { 
        start_point = points[i].split(",");
        end_point = points[i+1].split(",");

        distance += Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(end_point[0] - start_point[0], 2) +                                Math.pow(end_point[1] - start_point[1], 2)));
    }

    return distance;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I made a [new version here](https://jsfiddle.net/ft8yLuqy/2/). Now you can drag the targets to check the different results.